# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; Error making a migration table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to make a webshop using php, laravel, mysql and css. But when i try to make a migration table using foreign keys for products and orders i get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near `` 'unsigned not null, `description` text unsigned not null, `price` decimal(8, 2...' `` at line 1 (SQL: `` create table `orders` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `user_id` int unsigned not null, `product_id` int unsigned not null, `name` varchar(255) unsigned not null, `description` text unsigned not null, `price` decimal(8, 2) unsigned not null, `totalAmount` decimal(8, 2) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' ``)

This is how my migration table looks like as of this moment:

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->primary()->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('product_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->decimal('price');
            $table->decimal('totalAmount');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        });
```

Anyone that can help me solve this problem?

Comment: You might want to try [dba.se] I believe it is more suited for this kind of question

Comment: `$table->bigIncrements('id');` is enough. Or `$table->id();`. On laravel `id` column by default set as primary key and auto increament. So you no need to mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
$table->increments('id')->primary()->unsigned();
```

you could simply do this:

```
$table->id();
```

(At least for Laravel 7+)

Answer (score 0):

In the text of problematic query we see:

```
...
`name` varchar(255) unsigned not null, 
`description` text unsigned not null,
...
```

But the column of string type cannot have `UNSIGNED` attribute. This is an error.

I don't know why this occures in your case and how to heal this.

Answer (score 0):

> php artisan migrate:rollback

or

> php artisan migrate